# Update `index` property in a collection of given IDs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, position

Using a POST on my front-end (React.js, with `react-beautiful-dnd`), I'm trying to update the position of the items a user has stored.

My strategy is to send over an updated index of IDs that are ordered in the specified position.

**My Data** (example, simplified)

```
┌────┬────────┬───────┐
│ id │ title  │ index │ <── my "position"
├────┼────────┼───────┤
│  1 │ Apple  │     4 │
│  2 │ Banana │     1 │
│  3 │ Mango  │     3 │
│  4 │ Kiwi   │     2 │
│  5 │ Orange │     0 │
└────┴────────┴───────┘
```

**New positions array** (anatomy)

```
$value: sorted ids ------> [3, 2, 5, 1, 4]
                            :  :  :  :  :
$key:   new index will be…  0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

**The Code**

The controller ingests an array that derives the new positions from the keys of the array. It loops then through the collection of given IDs and reassigns them the updated index.

```
public function reorder(Request $request) {

    $newIndex = $request->newIndex;
    $items = Item::whereIn('id', $newIndex)->get();

    foreach ($newIndex as $key => $value) {
      // TODO: check if $item->index needs to be rewritten at all
      $item = $items->find($value);
      $item->index = $key;
      $item->save();
    }

    return response('Success', 200);
}
```

**`dd()` of `$request->input`**

```
array:1 [
  "newIndex" => array:5 [
    0 => 4
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
    3 => 5
    4 => 3
  ]
]
```

**The problem**

It seems… the code only works once? Did I miss something? The POST fires every time and the set array is accurate, so the issue is not on the frontend side of things.

Comment: Are you sure that `$request->newIndex` is an array?

Comment: Just checked! `gettype($request->newIndex)` returns `array`.

Comment: Asking just for sure: `$key` is supposed to be new index value and `$value` id of item?

Comment: Yes. I will edit the question to make it more explicit. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Have no clue what is going on there, can you simply dump `$request->input()` at the beggining of the controller?

Comment: this is the `dd()` of `$request->input()`
`
array:1 [
  "newIndex" => array:5 [
    0 => 4
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
    3 => 5
    4 => 3
  ]
]
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206243/discussion-between-harven-and-lucifero-von-nachtosphere).